# Getting radio button's value before form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, radio-button

How can I get radio button's value before form submission through PHP or jQuery?
It would be great if anybody could suggest some way :)

Comment: can you post the form submission code

Comment: You can't do it from PHP - your PHP code executes on the server when the form is submitted. Assuming you mean that you want to intercept the submit event and check the radio button's value at that point you can do it with JavaScript (with or without jQuery) - what have you tried?

Comment: @nnnnnn I've tried jQuery

var value = jQuery('#billing :radio:first').click(function(){
            //if (jQuery(this).is(':checked')){
              alert(jQuery('#billing :radio:first').val());
            //} 
          }

actually I want it's value on click event

Comment: If you want it on the click event then please update your question to say so (click "edit"). And put your code in the question, noting that you can format code by quoting it with the ` character, or by selecting it and clicking the `{}` button.

Comment: jQuery is not PHP either. your question has nothing to do with PHP. it is SERVER side language. Go figure.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do it with Javascript.

```
<script>

function getRadioValue(id) {
var radioBtn = document.getElementById(id);
alert(radioBtn.value);
}  

</script>


<form  action="" method="post">
    <input type="radio" id="btn1" name="123" value="value1" onclick="getRadioValue(this.id)"/>
    <input type="radio" id="btn2" name="123" value="value2" onclick="getRadioValue(this.id)"/>
    <input type="radio" id="btn3" name="123" value="value3" onclick="getRadioValue(this.id)"/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Please, on* attributes never have uppercase letters and never have "javascript:". Check http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp. Only hrefs may have "javascript:".

Comment: Thanks for the editing. But i don't think it matters much. Does  it? =/

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = $('#your-form :radio:first').val();
```

Comment: I want it's value on Click event.

Comment: jQuery("input[type=radio]").click(function(){
           
              var value = jQuery('#billing :radio:first')
              alert(value);
            
          });

Can I put it like this? @alex

Comment: @Amit - that says "when _any_ radio is clicked alert the value of the first radio within #billing" - is that what you intend?

Comment: @nnnnnn  I just want to see whether I get the value or not. Once I get I'll do other things with it.

Comment: @Amit - so why don't you go ahead and try the code you're posting? If you've got code already what actually is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Drive your users nuts:

```
<form onsubmit="alert(this.fooBar.value);" action=""
      onclick="alert(this.fooBar.value);">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="fooBar" value="foo bar">
    <input type="submit">
  </div>
</form>
```